# Vaadin calendar not showing span event

Tags: html, events, calendar, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin calendar. I have some issues here.

When i add month span event like January 27 to February 10, it shows in January but not in February (Month view). And when i add week span like Sunday to Wednesday it shows in first week but not 2nd (Weekly view). Same in Daily view - day span events.

On calendarView it gets events from DB and add events to MCalendar:

```
public void setEvents(List<SEvent> events) {
    
    BeanItemContainer items = new BeanItemContainer(SEvent.class);
    items.removeAllItems();
    items.addAll(events);
    ContainerEventProvider provider = new ContainerEventProvider(items);

    calendar.setEventProvider(provider);
}
```

Added screenshots down below

[image: Screenshots]

---

#### Solved

REASON: ContainerEventProvider has bug.
SOLUTION: calendar.addEvent([EachEvent]);

Comment: Can you post some code? It works for me. What is your Vaadin version?

Comment: Added some code on my question. I'm using Vaadin 7.5.5

Comment: It's because i'm using custom event. when i add Basic events it works fine. My SEvent is almost exactly same as basicEvent

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted to use your solution, but in the end I've noticed, that I've given the wrong sortPropertyId, so my container wasn't sorted, although it's a requirement for ContainerEventProvider, see in API:
https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/components/calendar/ContainerEventProvider.html

After having a right sorted (by start date) container, every events were displayed in every view mode.